# How to change index of a given list's element?

Tags: list, sorting, indexing, append

I have a list of 51 elements.
keypoints = ['0.49395501613616943', '0.3686272203922272', '0.9999948740005493'...]. The original index of my list goes in order from 0,1,2...50. But i have to set new indices to the elements of the list and order them accordingly in a new list. How can i do that?

My new indices:

```
NEW_INDEX = [39, 40, 41, 21, 22, 23,
27, 28, 29, 33, 34, 35, 24, 25, 26,
30, 31, 32, 36, 37, 38, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 
48, 49, 50, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17, 
6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 18, 19, 20, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Is this in a particular programming language?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this question is about python syntax.

In pure python, you can use a list comprehension and indices:

```py
keypoints = ['0.49395501613616943', '0.3686272203922272', '0.9999948740005493', '0.9473770229920709', '0.7699773520016487', '0.540962426318277']
new_index = [2, 1, 5, 4, 0, 3]

ordered_keypoints = [keypoints[i] for i in new_index]

print(ordered_keypoints)
# ['0.9999948740005493', '0.3686272203922272', '0.540962426318277', '0.7699773520016487', '0.49395501613616943', '0.9473770229920709']
```

Using numpy, there is an even more convenient notation:

```py
import numpy as np

keypoints = np.array(['0.49395501613616943', '0.3686272203922272', '0.9999948740005493', '0.9473770229920709', '0.7699773520016487', '0.540962426318277'])
new_index = np.array([2, 1, 5, 4, 0, 3])

ordered_keypoints = keypoints[new_index]

print(ordered_keypoints)
# ['0.9999948740005493' '0.3686272203922272' '0.540962426318277'
#  '0.7699773520016487' '0.49395501613616943' '0.9473770229920709']
```